# What happens to unused tags on sites that lack the tag cleanup script?

Tags: support, tags

On Scifi.SE, the tag cleanup script is disabled.  This means that when a tag is used once, it no longer is automatically deleted after 6 months.  However, what happens to tags that are now defunct/unused?

The example I have is [little-league](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-league), which is the former name of a web-comic.  Said web-comic is now named [JL8](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jl8), so I made a JL8 tag and edited the one question to use it.  But it looks like the [little-league](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-league) tag still exists.

Will a completely unused tag get cleaned up automatically?  As a diamond mod on scifi.SE, is there something I can/should do to clean up that tag?

Comment: The “cleanup” script that's disabled on SFF is the one that removes tags that are in use but have a single occurrence. There's a different script that removes tags with 0 occurrences, it runs every day.

Comment: @Gilles You want to make that an answer?

Comment: I think this situation is different enough from the possible duplicate question given the recent-ish development of the single-use tag script being disabled.

Comment: I don't see anything different about this situation. The tag cleanup job existed before the tag killer. The `little-league` tag became unused less than 24 hours ago. If it's still there and unused tomorrow, file a bug report.